# Tags are not updating instantly for new questions

Tags: support, live-refresh

I've been experiencing this for a while. Sometimes, (*oh, I mean always*), when you are on a certain tag, for instance [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), and you keep on waiting, an instant message displays `1 new question(s)..` or `X new question(s)...` automatically if a new question has been asked. But now, they won't show until I click <kbd>F5</kbd> on my keyboard or the refresh button on the browser.

What could be the possible reason(s) for this?

- Do I have a slow connection?
- Is that feature currently disabled on StackOverFlow?
- Is there any system maintenance?

**UPDATE**

Also, when you are talking for a certain user, the comment cannot be seen or even a notice that there is a new comment. Also there is no `RED` circle if a new message has arrived in your inbox.

Comment: What happens when you click on the banner that says there is one new question?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards no, the banner won't show. I can't click anything.

Comment: No baring, please; I've seen some of you in real life.

Comment: I had similar issues when visiting the site with a customized copy of Internet Explorer (don't ask).  I switched to Chrome and my problems went away.

Comment: @BobDuell i'm using `Chrome Version 24.0.1312.56 m`, i think probably the latest one.

Comment: @DerekFloss: In Chrome, go to `View` -> `Developer` -> `Developer` Tools, then to the `Network` tab. Click on the `WebSockets` category at the bottom. Refresh the page. Look for the socket connection to appear there. Click on it, it should say `Status: 101 Switching Protocols` and the `Frames` tab should show 3 entries.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I found this with "Tools -> Developer Tools" off the settings icon (or whatever that 3-bar icon in the upper right-hand corner is called). Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, aside from possibility of having system maintenance, *you have a slow internet connection* at that moment.

This happens to me while I'm downloading using `IDM`. It "eats" the whole connection, that's why the tags are not refreshing automatically. After downloads, the live refresh works again perfectly.

Comment: so true. I was downloading during that time the when banner won't show. I'll be back for confirmation. I'll download a large file again and see if the banner still won't refresh. *Actually live refresh is working now*

Comment: Tested. Thanks! I am downloading now and the live refresh isn't working.